# найти ближайшее нижнее и верхнее значения из столбца_2 для значения из столбца_1

Tags: sql

всем привет

допустим, у меня есть таблчками вот с таким столбцом:

| value |
| --- |
| 450 |
| 638 |
| 789 |

и я создал таблицу с таким столбцом

| block |
| --- |
| 299 |
| 399 |
| 499 |
| 599 |
| 699 |
| 799 |

мне нужно, чтобы выводилось ближайший нижний и верхний порог для каждого *value* из столбца *price_block* и получалось вот так:

| value | below_block | above_block |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 450 | 399 | 499 |
| 638 | 599 | 699 |
| 789 | 699 | 799 |

как правильно построить запрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с подзапросами

```
SELECT v
    ,(SELECT max(b) FROM blocks where b < v)
    ,(SELECT min(b) FROM blocks WHERE b > v)
    
FROM vals
```

похожий вариант с джойнами и группировкой

```
SELECT v, max(b1.b), min(b2.b)
FROM vals AS v
LEFT JOIN blocks AS b1 ON (b1.b < v)
LEFT JOIN blocks as b2 ON (b2.b > v)
GROUP BY v;
```

в зависимости от СУБД можно воспользоваться оконными функциями, например, пронумеровав значения и отобрав первые в группах

```
SELECT v, b1, b2
FROM  (
  SELECT v, b1.b as b1, b2.b as b2
    , row_number() over (partition by v order by b1.b DESC) as rn1
    , row_number() over (partition by v order by b2.b ASC) as rn2
  FROM vals 
  LEFT JOIN blocks as b1 ON b1.b < v
  LEFT JOIN blocks as b2 ON b2.b > v
) as t
WHERE rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1
```